# New Version view cut in landscape

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The New Version view is cut while viewing in landscape.
See image...

[image]

Comment: I will test again in v28, once v29 arrives...

Comment: sorry, I missed the word "view" for some reason.  Your question actually makes sense now.

Comment: Considering this page is only applicable during the alpha/beta, and you can easily enough reorient to portrait, this problem seems pretty darn minor...

Comment: Yes, it's minor. So?

Comment: It's not just that it's minor, but it is a non-issue once the app is actually released. The purpose of testing is to prepare for release, so I just don't know that it makes sense to fix cosmetic pre-release-exclusive issues.

Comment: So are you saying that once 1.0 is released, there won't be a new version again and/or they won't be using this screen, rather use the app store mechanism?

Comment: Actually, we might use this screen when we get to the Appstore – Android uses a similar upgrade mechanism.

Comment: @Idan, apologies for being unclear of what I meant, and per Arie, also wrong! *Requiring* updates seemed exclusive to testing (avoid reporting already fixed bugs from an old version), but if for different reasons it would be displayed in release, my point was moot. Presumably it will only be shown when major API changes required a phase out of the old app, and not every single minor revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should be fixed in version 0.1.29**. The upgrade notice will now look a little different:

[image: New Upgrade Notice UI]